# de sql server para mysql com php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, servidor

Tenho um banco `SqlServer` e preciso de, via script php, enviar os dados de uma tabela para um banco MySql.

O OPENQUERY resultará dentro da condição que tenho (script php)?

Qual a melhor forma de o fazer?

O código que uso para conectar os bancos:

SqlServer:

```
$conMsSql = odbc_connect('Banco_MsSql','User_MsSql','Pw_MsSql');
```

MySql:

```
$hostname_mysql = "localhost";
$database_mysql = "banco_mysql";
$username_mysql = "user_mysql";
$password_mysql = "pw_mysql";
$Conn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_mysql, $username_mysql, $password_mysql) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
$DBase = mysql_select_db($database_mysql,$Conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

E ficaria algo assim:

```
$query = mysql_query('insert into tabela1 ( col1, col2, col3 )
 select sqlserver.tab1.col1, sqlserver.tab1.col2, sqlserver.tab1.col3 from sqlserver.tab1')
```

Comment: São muitos registros? tentou fazer duas conexões uma para o ou mssql e outra para o mysql? se tiver o código fonte edite a pergunta e coloque ele.

Comment: Você precisa fazer uma rotina disso, ou fará esse importação de uma vez só?

Comment: Será uma rotina.

Comment: Você vai precisar criar um `crontab` no servidor para executar seu script no tempo que você definir (como o agendador de tarefas do windows), depois você precisará abrir as duas conexões no seu script e crie uma rotina que execute o mysqldump para criar o arquivo sql, pode ser com um hash aleatório: 123.sql, já fazendo as tratativa dos dados. Depois importe esse arquivo 123.sql para o banco sql server, usando `mssql_query()`, ou `sqlrv_query()`.

Comment: Quando finalizar a criação  do arquivo, você dispara o evento de importação.

Comment: Você não precisa necessariamente de um script php para fazer isso.

Comment: Vc pode criar uma `procedure` no `MySQL` que gere o arquivo numa pasta. E capturar esse arquivo numa `procedure`  no `SQL Server`.

Comment: Como é uma rotina, ele sempre estará executando de acordo com o tempo definido de espaço de execução entre os dos processamentos.

Comment: Eu só tenho permissão de consulta do banco SqlServer, daí fazer um select numa tabela e enviar para o MySql...

Comment: Esses campos, tabelas são iguais?

Answer (score 1):

Se o seu banco de dados for muito grande, o aconselhável é que sua rotina utilize um `script` de `backup` `mysqldump`, escrever este arquivo `SQL` em uma pasta e por fim ler este arquivo no `Sql Server` através de uma `procedure`.

Devido o tamanho do banco de dados, possivelmente ser grande, o ideal seria utilizar uma linguagem como `Java` e manter esse `applet`/`script` no seu servidor com uso de `thread`, assim o `Java` trataria dessa migração sem maiores problemas, como por exemplo o `timeout` ou outros controles/limites que as linguagens `serve-side` possuem.